# "The current request is not a multipart request" when trying to test with MockMvc without uploading any file

Tags: java, spring, http, junit, mockmvc

I want to test a RequestMapping which takes some information about an item and then persists it, it also allows for images to be uploaded. However, the image uploading is not mandatory and my HTML form is using: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I am trying to test the controller without actually uploading any files, the controller looks like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addItem(
        @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Integer id,
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name,
        @RequestParam(value="image", required=false) MultipartFile file,
        ) throws IOException {

    // some stuff here

    ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView();
    return mov;

}
```

Even though I've set the `required` flag to be `false` I am getting the issue of a missing parameter, but more importantly, is it possible to send headers in the mockMvc request which would allow me to test this mapping without the need for uploading any images?

```java
    mockMvc.perform(post("https://localhost/store-admin/items/itemAddSubmit")
            .param("id", 1)
            .param("name", "testname").with(csrf()))
            .andDo(print());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multipart request you need to use `fileUpload` method instead of `get`, `post` or whatever.

Update your code as follows -

```
mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("https://localhost/store-admin/items/itemAddSubmit")
            .param("id", 1)
            .param("name", "testname").with(csrf()))
            .andDo(print());
```

To actually send a file use the `file` function with `fileUpload` as shown below -

```
mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("https://localhost/store-admin/items/itemAddSubmit")
            .file(myMockMultipartFile)
            .param("id", 1)
            .param("name", "testname").with(csrf()))
            .andDo(print());
```

where `myMockMultipartFile` is a `MockMultipartFile` object.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't realise that there was a `fileUpload` request type.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting an error when using this exact same format - stating that the parameter is not present (which in his case would be "file"). Is there perhaps something I am not denoting correctly? Expanding upon your answer would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @degreesightdc are you sure you are passing all arguments? It would be better if you start own question with error stacktrace and other relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

Very important to note - if the [`@RequestParam` that accepts the **file**] on your REST endpoint doesn't have a "`value=`" attribute set, it will also throw the same type of an error when running a mock test. You could have ignored the "value" attribute when running the solution in prod and not experienced any error, but doing so would prevent you from running a test and injecting in the file programmatically.

Ex:

```
@RequestParam(value="file") final MultipartFile file,
```

Your question already showed this properly, but I want to document this answer for users in the future who may, like myself, overlook such a small detail.

Cheers